# Error While creating a C shared library with MATLAB to use in VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, matlab, shared-libraries, matlab-deployment

I'm trying to make a C shared library.

I'm a newbie in Matlab, so I follow these steps:

http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-UR7P0/index.html?solution=1-UR7P0

I've created the Matlab files as it's written in article, and did all the steps with guidance of article. When I build my solution, I get this error..

**error LNK1104: cannot open file 'foolib.lib'**

Note: My MATLAB version is `7.11.0.584(r2010b)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the **foolib.lib** to the linker dependencies in Visual studio.
*Right-Click on project -> Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.*
Add full path to foolib.lib here, for example "C:\MyProject\MyLib\foolib.lib"

This is described as step 6 at your link:

> 6 -  After specifying the library directories, select the Input category and type the following libraries in the Additional Dependencies field:
>   mclmcrrt.lib
>   foolib.lib"